# NullPointerException when adding a new row to tableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have an activity with a `LinearLayout` and a `TableLayout` inside.  I want to add data programmatically to this table but every time I get a null pointer exception.  I tried to clean my project but I still have the same error null pointer exception in this instruction :

```
iptable.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
       TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

In the `OnCreate` method I have:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iposition);
    session=new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    ActionBar actionbar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    TableLayout iptable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.ip_table);

    TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
    tr_head.setId(10);
    tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    TextView label_Item = new TextView(this);
    label_Item.setId(20);
    label_Item.setText("Valeur");
    label_Item.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    label_Item.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    tr_head.addView(label_Item);

    TextView label_Quantity = new TextView(this);
    label_Quantity.setId(21);
    label_Quantity.setText("Quantite"); 
    label_Quantity.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    label_Quantity.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); 
    tr_head.addView(label_Quantity); 

    tr_head.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    iptable.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
           TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

In `activity_iposition`, I have :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/itempositionlayout">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1"
        android:id="@+id/ip_table" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please show logcat log.

Comment: thx for your attention my problem is solved i just had to use a LinearLayout instead of relative i don't why but it works and clean and rebuild project again

Comment: @elpazio instead of changing your Layout, look at your Logcat to see why you were getting a NullPointerException. When you change the layout, you're just masking the problem and not actually fixing what could cause you headaches in the future.

Comment: actually it was not exactly the layout it was cleaning and rebuilding the project

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to clean the projet and rebuild it and everything works fine ... i moved the code relative of adding the new row inside a new method to call it at the end of the onCreate method i get a NullPointerException